# how to add and multiply real numbers in cmake expression

Tags: cmake

I am doing below operation on floating variables in cmake .

I read an earlier stack overflow cmake posts and modified my code for executing below expression. But I am not getting expected result:

Results:

```
### RESULT 30
### A 20.0
```

Expected results:

```
### RESULT 30.0
### A 20.0
```

---

cmake

```
set(A 20.0)
set(B 80.0)

set(loop 1 ) #0 1 2 3 4 5)

function(ARTH_OPER expr output)
    execute_process(COMMAND awk "BEGIN {print ${expr}}" OUTPUT_VARIABLE __output)
    set(${output} ${__output} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

foreach(loop_val ${loop})

   ARTH_OPER("${A} + ${loop_val} * 10" RESULT)
   message("### RESULT ${RESULT}")
   message("### A ${A}")

endforeach(loop_val)
```

How can I get the expected result.

Comment: So, you just print a value of the expression `20.0 + 1 * 10` in **awk** and it gives you `30.0` instead of `30` which you expect. Why do you ask about CMake instead of awk?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think it's the other way around. OP expects `30.0` but gets `30` - but I agree that  it should probably have been tagged with [tag:awk] too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `awk`'s `printf` function and use the `%f` format string for printing floating point numbers and `.1` to print with one decimal. Combined it becomes `%.1f`:

```
execute_process(COMMAND awk "BEGIN {printf(\"%.1f\", ${expr})}" OUTPUT_VARIABLE __output)
```

Comment: Yes.It working with you suggestion.Thanks a lot for your answer.